# AngularJs filter with array of values

Tags: angularjs, filter

is it possible to filter $scope.items by comparing them with an array? And put the result in $scope.itemsfiltered?
The following url explains it all (scroll downwards): http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/08/tip-accessing-filtered-array-outside-ng-repeat/

I've tried a function that compared all items with some array values and it works.
But the result only shows up when I assign the result to $scope.items, not when I assign it to $scope.itemsfiltered.

So A) something like above (see code below)

Or B) Something more simple, a regex or something to compare with... so a model "filtereditem" is not necessary, and just do: $scope.filterByRegexOrSomethingElse = /compare1|compare2/;

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in (itemsfiltered = (items | filter:filterByArr))">
    {{ title }}
</div>

$scope.filterByArray = function () {
    var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];

    // do some magic here
    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        //  resetScope($scope);
        if (_.contains(arr, items[i].categorie)) {
            filtered.push( items[i] );
        }
    }

    $scope.itemsfiltered = filtered;
};
```

Comment: What is your question? How to filter an array or why `$scope.itemsfiltered = filtered;` isn't working?

Comment: Take your pick, whatever works...

Comment: In your code change: `item in (itemsfiltered = (items | filter:filterByArr))` to `item in itemsfiltered | filter:filterByArr` and try?

Comment: sorry, im a bit confused. Are you trying to use the filter function to modify the model too?

Comment: I will edit the question, I have actualy a model named "items" wich contains the items. The model "filtereditems" contains the filtered model "items". The following url explains it all (scroll downwards): http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/08/tip-accessing-filtered-array-outside-ng-repeat/

Answer (score 0):

```
            $scope.filterCategory = function() {
            if ($(this)[0].category) {
                if ($scope.categories.indexOf($(this)[0].filter.value) == -1) {
                    $scope.categories.push($(this)[0].filter.value);
                }
            } else {
                var indexToRemove = $scope.categories.indexOf($(this)[0].filter.value);
                if (indexToRemove != -1) {
                    $scope.categories.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
                }
            }

            $scope.queryFilter = function(item) {
              return $scope.categories.length ? _.contains($scope.categories, item.categorie) : true;
            };
        };
```